# Add surface/line to 3D stem plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, surface, stem

Say I have a 3D stem plot using stem3

```
stem3(xx,yy,zz,'red')
```

[image]

I want to add a line or a semitransparent surface to a height of 550 (zz = 550). is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with just a normal `surf` object.

```
% Create your stem3 object
stem3(rand(10), rand(10), rand(10) * 700, 'r');

hold on

% Get the current X and Y Limits of the axes
xdata = get(gca, 'xlim');
ydata = get(gca, 'ylim');

% Ensure that the axes limimts don't change when we plot the surface
axis manual

% Create a surface that spans the axes and is of height 550 (the third input)
% Use alpha value of 0.1 for the face transparency
surf(xdata, ydata, 550 * ones(2), 'FaceAlpha', 0.1, 'FaceColor', 'red');
```

[image]